# Access 2010 Navigation Forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, navigation

Is it possible to load a table from the Navigation Form?

I would like the table to appear in the Navigation subform in the same way that a form or report appears.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a table in any kind of form. However you can create a datasheet form, and then use that form. How a datasheet form displays is indistinguishable from a table view. So such forms look the same as a table.

So simply create a datasheet view and use that in the navigation control and the result is a table like view in the navigation control.